# what is the diifferent between cin.ignore(1); and cin.ignore(n)?

Tags: c++, cin, getline

I learned that `cin.ignore(1);` is using to prevent some bug like below

```
cin.get(mystring,255);
//if I didn't use cin.ignore second cin.get will not work
cin.ignore(1);
cin.get(mystring2,255);
```

but what is the difference between `cin.ignore(1)` and `cin.ignore(255)`?  What is the actual meaning of `cin.ignore`?  Why use it instead of just two `cin>>x`?

Comment: [Did you read the documentation?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)?

Comment: @DannyuNDos that's quite unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry, but I wanted...

Answer (score 1):

`cin.ignore(1)`

will ignore the first character.

`cin.ignore(n)`

will ignore the next `n` characters.

Comment: Recommend removing the "numbers or" because everything is characters here and you don't want the ambiguity of someone thinking they can ignore 12345 as one number.